# Unexpected behavior from Inner[]

Tags: inner

Does anyone know why Inner[] behaves differently in the last of these three examples?

```
Inner[f, {a, b}, {e1, e2}, List]
```

> `{f[a, e1], f[b, e2]}`

```
Inner[f, {a, b}, {{1, 0}, e2}, List]
```

> `{f[a, {1, 0}], f[b, e2]}`

```
Inner[f, {a, b}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, List]
```

> `{{f[a, 1], f[b, 0]}, {f[a, 0], f[b, 1]}}`

Why didn't the last case return `{f[a, {1, 0}], f[b, {0, 1}]}`?

[image]

I am using Mathematica 11.

Comment: Please post your code as copyable plain text rather than an image. The easier it is for someone to reproduce your example, the more likely you'll get a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like `Dot`, `Inner` doesn't always operate `f` on the elements on the first levels of the input lists:

> Like Dot, Inner effectively contracts the last index of the first tensor with the first index of the second tensor. Applying Inner to a rank r tensor and a rank s tensor gives a rank r+s-2 tensor.

In other words, since you're contracting a vector (rank 1) and a matrix (rank 2) you end up with a rank 1 list if you use a general function for the last argument of `Inner`:

```
Inner[f, {a, b}, {{0, 1}, {2, 3}}, g]
```

> {g[f[a, 0], f[b, 2]], g[f[a, 1], f[b, 3]]}

To get the result you really want, it's probably easier to use `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[f, {{a, b}, {{0, 1}, {2, 3}}}]
```

> {f[a, {0, 1}], f[b, {2, 3}]}